# Cannot get a html page in Node.js

Tags: html, node.js, express

I was able to show the home page in this case index.html, but the page that I want open like a link not be displayed. Here's my code when i show the index.html:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/index.html'));
 });
```

A body of index.html:

```
<body>
  <div style="margin:100px;">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Express HTML</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="../app/public/signup.html">Signup</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="../app/public/login.html">Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

A problem is that i try a lot of ways to show singup.html and login.html
and it's not working. 
If anyone has a solution?Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `path.join` slightly incorrectly; `path.join` takes three parameters, not a singular 'pre-joined' parameter.

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/index.html'));
```

Should be:

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public', 'index.html'));
```

Alternately, you could just skip the join entirely:

```
res.sendFile( __dirname + "/public/" + "index.html" );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that didn't solve my problem. The problem is that I want to show signup.html and login.html pages, which are supposed to be opened by clicking on the 2 buttons on index.html page. It doesn't work tho, like the path is not correct.